# Is there a way to integrate QuickBooks Desktop to modify the on hand quantity for the item?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to integrate with QBs pro (2016) to modify the total on hand quantity. 
Attached screenshot is how you can update an item on hand quantity in QuickBooks Pro:
1. Click the InventoryActivities icon[image: click the Inventory Activities icon]
2. Select an item, and manually update the new quantity. [image]
3. OR, If you have a receiving, or sales, the item on hand quantity can also change (receiving can increase the quantity, sales will decrease the quantity).

My question is, right now I have an external web app that keeps track of the on hand quantity, and would like to integrate with QBs desktop to change the on hand quantity field. I've tried direct csv import and it won't allow me to change the on hand field, so I was wondering if I use QB web connector, will it be able to change/update the on hand quantity?

Comment: Worth noting that what you're showing in your screenshot is *not* directly modifying the Quantity On Hand value. You're actually creating an Inventory Adjustment *transaction*, which modifies the Quantity On Hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to use InventoryAdjustment to modify the Quantity on hand.
See the OSR - http://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

All development for the desktop will need to be done through the QBXML SDK.
https://developer.intuit.com/v2/docs/0250_qb

To connect to a web application, you will need to use the QB Web Connector (QBWC) included with QB desktop. There is a QBWC server sample included in the SDK along with programmer guides for QBXML and QBWC.

If you are using PHP, there is an open source project available that has the server built and sample requests.
http://consolibyte.com/quickbooks-open-source/

Comment: For the above adjusting the inventory on hand, do you think there's any way  by using just import (i am not talking about 3rd party software)? maybe not importing by csv/excel file, but by importing through XML or IIF file?